# ant jdb return immediately from a task

Tags: java, ant, jdb

I'm wanting use ant to run a class and then the debugger (jdb) or the other way round

Whichever way round I do it I need one to return immediately as the other needs to attach...

here's the two tasks I'm working on at the moment... (where debug is the target run)

```
<target
    name="run-debug-target"
    depends="compile" >
    <java
        fork="true"
        classname="uk.co.bedroomcoders.ple.desktop.DesktopLauncher"
        classpath="bin:libs/gdx-backend-lwjgl.jar:libs/gdx-backend-lwjgl-natives.jar:libs/gdx.jar:libs/gdx-natives.jar" >
        <jvmarg line="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=localhost:6000,server=y,suspend=y" />
    </java>
</target>

<target
    name="debug"
    depends="run-debug-target"
    description="debugs the project compiling if needed" >
    <exec spawn="true" executable="jdb">    
        <arg value="-listen" />
        <arg value="localhost:6000"/> 
    </exec>
</target>
```

Comment: what is the problem that u're facing? `I need one to return immediately as the other needs to attach`... u'll need to specify the **error / requirement** clearly.

Comment: if one task does not return immediately the other cannot run and the debugger cannot attach to the program to be debugged

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Ant launch two java applications concurrently?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158937/can-ant-launch-two-java-applications-concurrently)

Comment: if they were *both* java applications...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html

See the `spawn` property:

> if enabled allows to start a process which will outlive ant.
>   Requires fork=true, and not compatible with timeout, input, output, error, result attributes.

So..

```
<java
    fork="true"
    spawn="true"
    classname="uk.co.bedroomcoders.ple.desktop.DesktopLauncher"
    classpath="bin:libs/gdx-backend-lwjgl.jar:libs/gdx-backend-lwjgl-natives.jar:libs/gdx.jar:libs/gdx-natives.jar" >
    <jvmarg line="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=localhost:6000,server=y,suspend=y" />
</java>
```

In this way, `<java>` task will start a new java process running the java class and return immediately without waiting for the process to return.