# Running One Server and Two Clients using ANT

Tags: java, ant, rmi

I am a newbie into ANT world. My Application is based on Client-Server architecture which is using "RMI" for communication.

I need to write an ANT build script which automatically compiles the whole code, starts the server and run two clients connected to that server.

Here's structure of my current `build.xml` file.(I am not sure what's wrong)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project default="runClientOne" name="MyFirstAntProject">   
    <target name="compile">     
        <javac srcdir="./src" destdir="classfiles" />       
    </target>       
    <target name="runServer" depends="compile" >
        <java classname="com.jain.RMIServer">
            <classpath path="classfiles" />
        </java>
    </target>       
    <target name="runClientOne" depends="runServer">            
        <java classname="com.jain.RMIClient" fork="true" taskname="A" >
            <classpath path="classfiles" />
            <arg value="localhost"/>
            <arg value="Sumit"/>
        </java>
        <java classname="com.jain.RMIClient" fork="true" taskname="B">
            <classpath path="classfiles" />
            <arg value="localhost"/>
            <arg value="Sushil"/>
        </java>
    </target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Guys,

I have figured out that I will have to use the `<parallel>My CODE </parallel>` .

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this question when I was trying to accomplish a similar thing, here is how I achieved a target that starts running the server and client. (My answer expands on Sushil's and this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158937/can-ant-launch-two-java-applications-concurrently))

Here is the case: I have a server, and when I start up I want 3 clients to connect to the server right away, all in a separate process.

The trick is to nest `parallel` and `sequential` in the `build.xml` targets *individually*.

The sleep call can be changed to wait on the process too.

```
   <target name="start-all" depends="build" 
                  description="Starts 1 Server and 2 clients ">
     <parallel>
       <sequential>
         <java classname="Server" fork="true">
           <classpath refid="master-classpath"/>
           <arg line="${port}"/>
         </java>
       </sequential>
       <sequential>
          <sleep milliseconds="500"/>
          <antcall target="start-client">
          <param name="server.address" value="localhost" />
          <param name="server.port" value="${port}"/>
          </antcall>
       </sequential>
     </parallel>
   </target>
```

This would start the server, and then the clients, alternatively, using `<daemon>` to start the server and then immediately launching the clients right after.