# How to open multiple terminals using ant scripting?

Tags: java, ant

I have created one files sharing application using socket programming where there is a indexing server and few clients are connected to server. I have to created one automation script using ant but i can only open one terminal with help of jar. how to open multiple terminals with help of one jar so that all clients and server terminals get open in just one click.

****Please find build ant file below:-****

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <project name="fax" basedir="." default="build">
   <property name="src.dir" value="src"/>
   <property name="web.dir" value="war"/>
   <property name="build.dir" value="${web.dir}/WEB-INF/classes"/>
   <property name="name" value="fax"/>
   <property name="projectName" value="Test" />   

   <path id="master-classpath">
      <fileset dir="${web.dir}/WEB-INF/lib">
         <include name="*.jar"/>
      </fileset>
      <pathelement path="${build.dir}"/>
   </path>

   <target name="build" description="Compile source tree java files">
      <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
      <javac destdir="${build.dir}" source="1.5" target="1.5"           includeantruntime="true">
         <src path="${src.dir}"/>
         <classpath refid="master-classpath"/>
      </javac>
   </target>

   <jar destfile = "${web.dir}/lib/util.jar"
         basedir = "${build.dir}/">

   <manifest>
      <attribute name = "Main-Class" value = "Client1"/>
   </manifest>

   </jar>

   <target name="clean" description="Clean output directories">
      <delete>
         <fileset dir="${build.dir}">
            <include name="**/*.class"/>
         </fileset>
      </delete>
    </target>
  </project>
```

Comment: Are you trying to launch more than one java process at the same time? Your example is confusing because it only shows build logic

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158937/can-ant-launch-two-java-applications-concurrently/2180665#2180665